# Passing non-contiguous argument to contiguous dummy array in a Fortran procecdue

Tags: fortran, contiguous, fujitsu-fortran

Recently I encountered unexpected behavior of Fujitsu Fortran Version 2.0.0 while dealing with a subroutine which has dummy array with  the `contiguous` attribute.

I have reduced the problem to a simple example which is here:

```
program test
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: t
  INTEGER :: i, j
  ALLOCATE(t(3,3))
  DO i = 1, 4
   DO j = 1, 4
     t(i,j) = i*j
     !!PRINT *, t(i,j)
   END DO
  END DO
  CALL fun(t(2,1:4:2))
  DEALLOCATE(t)

  CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE fun(arg)
      ! Contiguous dummy argument arg
      INTEGER, CONTIGUOUS :: arg(:)
      PRINT *, arg(2)
    END SUBROUTINE
end program test
```

That pice of code can be successfully compiled by gfortran (GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0) but fails on cluster with Fujitsu Fortran compiler (mentioned above) giving the following error code:

```
"test_contiguous.f90", line 13: The actual argument number 1 of procedure 'fun' corresponding to a dummy argument 'arg' with the CONTIGUOUS attribute must be contiguous.
```

I am confused because as I understood compiler should make a contiguous temporary at the entrance of the subroutine (as is shown for example here: [Fortran 2008 contiguous](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAT4T_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.linux.doc/language_ref/contiguous.html))

In fact I have two questions:

1. What is specification for such situation?
2. Can it be a flag for compiler forcing him to create a contiguous temporary for such case?

I am trying to build third-party software and cannot change the source as I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fortran 2008 specification says (5.3.7) of assumed-shape dummy arguments with the `contiguous` attribute:

> The CONTIGUOUS attribute specifies that an assumed-shape array can only be argument associated with a contiguous effective argument, or that an array pointer can only be pointer associated with a contiguous target.

The Fortran 2018 specification, on the other hand, says (8.5.7):

> The CONTIGUOUS attribute specifes that an assumed-shape array is contiguous, that an array pointer can only be pointer associated with a contiguous target, or that an assumed-rank dummy data object is contiguous.

As can be seen, one restricts the effective argument (in this case `t(2,1:4:2)` of the main program) and the other does not.

It should be noted, though, that the restriction here is a restriction on the program which the compiler is not required to detect/enforce.  The compiler is free to accept, making a temporary copy, a non-contiguous argument even in Fortran 2008 mode. In neither case *must* the compiler make a temporary copy.

---

As to whether a specific compiler has options to relax its assumptions, I can't say in this case: I have no access to this one to test.  I'm happy for someone to edit into this answer such an option should one be found.